# Remove/Replace a \ in string

Tags: c#, regex

This code will only remove the " from the string. How can I get it to recognize I want the \ removed or replaced?

```
string[] parts = line.Replace("\"","");
```

Comment: `Replace` doesn't return string array. What are you try to do exactly? Backslash is an [escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) character. You need to escape it when you use in a `string`.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the escape character? e.g. "\\"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be using the following, because `\` is a special string character. It therefore needs to be escaped.

```
string part = line.Replace("\\", String.Empty);
```

It's a little unclear as to whether you want to replace a speech mark too. If you do then instead use the following, in this case you need to escape the speech mark too:

```
string part = line.Replace("\\\"", String.Empty);
```

Note that part is **not** an array so you should assign to a String. If instead you want to separate on that character to get an array you should use the following.

```
string[] parts = line.split('\\');
```

Comment: `line.Split('\');` does not work. It still needs to be escaped

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!! Much appreciated the knowledge, which Im sure is basic to you all..;)

Answer (score 3):

"\" is an escaped character. Use:

```
string parts = line.Replace("\\","");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think op wants to replace `"` also,

```
string[] parts = line.Replace(@"\""","");
```